# C# Lambda? In list of class find highest property (int) where property (character) = 1

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a List of Node where Node class has properties:

`public int ID;`

`public MovingObject character;`

I need to, maybe using Lambda, iterate the List and get the highest ID where character = X

I tried Linq extension methods GroupBy and OrderByDescending which does give me the highest ID but that leaves out where character = x. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) method to filter the collection by the objects who has a character 'x'.

```
var result = items.Where(item => item.character == X).OrderByDescending(item => item.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Would I be able to do the same without using an ID property but the index of the list element instead?

Comment: @rcast do you mean for the OrderBy? Well, you can reverse the list and then filter (using Where) or filter and then reverse the result (using the Reverse method). That should keep the ordering of the original list. Another way is to use the Select method with overload that passes the index of each item to generate a new anonymous type that contains an Index property in addition to the original object and then use it in the OrderByDescending method instead of the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Where` to filter. Then just ordering and getting the first will find the item you want.

```
var value = myList.Where(x => object.Equals(x.Character, "h"))
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
// check for null
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach: Filter out nodes with "X" character. Find the highest ID among the filtered out nodes. Search for the node with this ID.

The code:

```
var highestId = nodes.Where(n => n.Character == "X").Max(n => n.ID);
var highestNode = nodes.Single(n => n.ID == highestId);
```